# Making a WPF TextBlock be only grow and not shrink?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

In my app I set the `Text` of the `TextBlock` named `tbkStatus` many times.

How can I make the `TextBlock` be just grow auto to fit the text but not shrink when the text changed?

The `StatusText` changes every few seconds, There are statuses with long text and short text.
I want my TextBlock to fit itself to the size of the longest text that was, and even when there is a short text the TextBlock should not shrink

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="200" Width="400" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Topmost="True">
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Please wait ..." Grid.Row="1" Margin="6"/>

        <TextBlock Name="tbkStatus" Grid.Row="2" Margin="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding StatusText}"/>

        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="3" Margin="6" Height="20"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="24,3" Margin="6" Content="Stop"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Show the xaml markup of the `TextBlock`, and the container surrounding it.

Comment: I cant really reproduce this. What exactly is the desired behavior you are expecting?

Comment: set the min width property to the amount you desire to avoid the shrink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xaml only solution:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusText}"
           MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

This way whenever the `Width` growths, `MinWidth` growths too. Hence, the control can't shrink back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just listen to Layout Events like [`SizeChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`LayoutUpdated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated(v=vs.110).aspx) or write some sort of behavior

In the below example, the basic premise is to listen to either of these events, and force your control to never shrink

> **Note** this is totally untested and was just an idea, maybe you could set the `MinWidth` Property instead

**Xaml**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbkStatus" SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private double _lastSize;

private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    if (textBlock == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (e.WidthChanged)
    {
        if (textBlock.Width < _lastSize)
        {
            textBlock.Width = _lastSize;
        }
        _lastSize = textBlock.Width;
    }
}
```

**Also Note**

The [`SizeChangedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.sizechangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) Class has many properties that you might be able to take advantage of

Comment: I guess it will only work for the first time but after you explicitly set the width you will not get an OnSizeChanged event again.

Comment: @googlefan yeah thats why i was thinking something Like MinWidth

Comment: Why not use it at `TextChanged`, if the `Text` is longer than before update the `Width` otherwise do nothing.

Comment: @LionKing yes that is fair enough as well

Comment: Please write an answer that was tried and worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
 <TextBlock Name="tbkStatus" Grid.Row="2" Margin="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding StatusText}"/>
```

Since `TextBlock` doesn't have `TextChange` event this will do that job

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty, typeof(TextBlock));
int textLength =0 


dp.AddValueChanged(tbkStatus, (object a, EventArgs b) =>
{
      if (textLength < tbkStatus.Text.Length)
      {
       textLength = tkbStatus.Text.Length;
       tbkStatus.Width = textLength * SomeValue; //You have to play around and see what value suits you best since it depends on font and it's size
      }

});
```

Alternatively, you can use a `TextBox` and make it read only and use the `TextChanged` event.

Comment: It does not suit me, I added an explanation to my question. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer, you can combine what @Saruman provided as answer and what I did and have good solution for your problem.

Comment: Can you please write a sample code that has been tested and is working?

Comment: @googlefan take a look, I think this should work. Since I don't have visual studio right now, I didn't check it.